# rotating cogs in java

Tags: java, animation

First of all my english is rubbish, so please understand.

I have been asked to do a little simulation/animation in java. 
I have a few cog on board one of the cogs rotates all the time on its axis. when I move any other cog close to the rotating one it has to start rotating  and teeth can not overlap each other.

I think this link describes it quite well
http://www.csharphelper.com/howto_animate_gear.gif

I don't know how to make this cogs interact together, i will be really happy if some can show some code example

Many thanks for any help

Comment: The answers below are correct - is this a simulation or an animation?  The difference is that the first is accurate and the second *looks* accurate.  It depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 6):

If you know how to rotate the kog, you could cheat a bit, and hard-code the timing so that they rotate at the right time :P

Comment: I would second that. The alternative would be to use a full-blown physics engine, but that would be overkill. Everything else would be insane.

Comment: Hard code the timings, it's a simple exercise and this is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic LCM ([Least Common Multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)) problem: try to formulate a solution from the dimensions (radius or diameter or circumference) of the cogs.